Use PowerMock to mock java.io.File not effectively
I have code such as:
File file = File createTempFile(“xxx”, “txt”);

So, when I use PowerMock to mock this file object, such as:
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({File.class,StringUtils.class})

…

PowerMockito.mockState(File.class);
PowerMockito.when(File.createTempFile(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()).thenReturn(null);

PowerMockito.mockState(StringUtils.class);
PowerMockito.when(StringUtils.isEmpty().thenReturn(false);

When I run the code, this file object is not null, the file is other create by I input parameters.but when I use the same code to mock the org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils#isEmpty is effectively .When i debug, StringUtils.isEmpty() return false, the code is effectively.
The PowerMock version is 2.0.7

You have .thenReturn(null) – what do you expect it to return?

Do you mean "this file is not null"? @Mureinik you changed the OP's "nois" to "is" - so I thought perhaps they mean't "is not" which would then make the question understandable as it would be an unexpected result.

@k314159 hmm... perhaps. I didn't consider that was a possibility.  Feel free to revert this edit.

I don't really understand the question; I was only guessing what was meant. Chenet, please [edit] and clarify your question. I appreciate you are not a native English speaker, so consider using a grammar checker such as https://languagetool.org/ or similar site.

thinks, I re-edited my question.

@k314159 you're right.I use my mobile phone to edit the problem, and my mother tongue is not English, so the description of the problem is a little wrong.

When you write PowerMockito.mockState do you mean mockStatic? Also, are you actually passing StringUtils.class.class or just StringUtils.class? You should copy and paste the actual code that you're using. The code that you show must be reproducible.

You explicitly specified .thenReturn(null), so it's not a surprise that you get null.
You could of course explicitly return something else, such as a mock object:
File mockFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
PowerMockito.when(File.createTempFile(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()).thenReturn(mockFile);


Sorry, i was wrong, this file is not null
